# Nhibernate criteria future translate to linq

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

I need to translate following queries into linq.

```
IEnumerable<User> data = myquery.Future<User>();
IFutureValue<long> count = totalcountQuery.FutureValue<long>();
```

Thanks

**Update:**
 **

```
myQuery = session.Query<User>()
               .Skip(pageIndex * pageSize)
               .Take(pageSize);

 totalCount = session.Query<User>().LongCount(); 
 dbUsers = myQuery.ToFuture();
 var count = myQuery.LongCount();
 totalRecords = (int)count.Value; **//Here is the error**
```

**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<User> data = myquery.ToFuture<User>();
IFutureValue<long> count = totalcountQuery.ToFutureValue<long>();
```